# CSS <button> to look exactly like <a> displays wrong (offset to bottom)

Tags: html, css, button

This is a page example: [link](https://bucard.co.il/@MyExample123)

You can see the WeChat widget (the green one) is a `<button>` type while all the other links are `<a href>` type, and I added the button `class="remove-btn-styles"` so it will look like them.

You can see everything in the F12 that it have the same CSS as the `<a>` tags, and yet the button is a bit offset to the bottom than the `<a>` tags.

Some code (Look at the button at the bottom):

```
<div class="luxery-logos-tiles">
    <li class="inner-original-icon-li">
        <a href="1" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
            <img src="/images/luxeryLogos/facebook.png" alt="SocialMediaFacebook">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="inner-original-icon-li">
        <a href="21321" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
            <img src="/images/luxeryLogos/instagram.png" alt="SocialMediaInstagram">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="inner-original-icon-li">
        <a href="1232131" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
            <img src="/images/luxeryLogos/youtube.png" alt="SocialMediaYoutube">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="inner-original-icon-li">
        <button class="remove-btn-styles">
            <img src="/images/luxeryLogos/weChat.png" alt="SocialMediaWeChat">
        </button>
    </li>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.luxery-logos-tiles {
    margin-top: 5vh;
    margin-bottom: 5vh;
}


.inner-original-icon-li {
    margin: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: all .5s;
}

.inner-original-icon-li a, .inner-original-icon-li button {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1.3em;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    transition: all .5s;
}

.inner-original-icon-li a img, .inner-original-icon-li button img {
    display: block;
    transition: all .5s;
}

.inner-original-icon-li a:hover img, .inner-original-icon-li button:hover img {
    transform: scale(0.8);
}

.inner-original-icon-li a img, .inner-original-icon-li button img {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
}

.remove-btn-styles {
    background: none;
    color: inherit;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    font: inherit;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none !important;
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: @Paulie_D Allright, changed it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the button is the correct one. If you remove the `display: block` from the images and fix the padding around it by setting it the same on every side, they all look the same:

```css
.inner-original-icon-li a, .inner-original-icon-li button {
  display: inline-block;
  /* same padding on every side */
  padding: 1.3em;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.inner-original-icon-li a img, .inner-original-icon-li button img {
  /* display: block; */
  transition: all .5s;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think `<a>`tag has no it's real size. so it changes to its content size.
In your case, its size is image size in it.

But, button has its real size.

So, button and `<a>` looks as the same, but in fact, `<a>` is smaller than button.
So they aligned to top and button is a bit offset to the bottom.

I think you can fix this issue by adding this css code.

```
.luxery-logos-tiles {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

[image: Fun-And-Solution]

Comment: You can confirm it by looking at inspect.

Comment: Your code only centres the buttons/links vertically, but the wechat button is still smaller than the other ones.

Comment: Try to remove "align-items: center;".

Comment: Yes, it's better but it's no longer responsive without `flex-wrap`. Is there any reason we try to keep adding unnecessary stuff here instead of fixing the original issue (`padding` and `display`)?